# Laravel owner middleware not working

Tags: laravel

I created a middleware (app/Http/Middleware/AbortIfNotOwner.php), this is code from another Stackoverflow post

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use DB;

class AbortIfNotOwner
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string    $resourceName
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $resourceName)
    {
        $resourceId = $request->route()->parameter($resourceName);

        $user_id = \DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)->user_id;

        if ($request->user()->id != $user_id) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I register it in the app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     'owner' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AbortIfNotOwner',
];
```

and in my route file I have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['owner:bids']], function() {
        Route::get('user/{id}/bids', ['as' => 'buyer_bids', 'uses' => 'User\Buyer\BidsController@getBidsPerUser']);
    });
```

When I run this code I get an

> ErrorException in AbortIfNotOwner.php line 23: Trying to get property
>   of non-object

This refers to the following lines in the middleware:

```
> $resourceId = $request->route()->parameter($resourceName);
> $user_id = \DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)->user_id;
```

The issue seems to be that resourceId is null I think. I do have a field user_id in the bids table, so am not sure what is wrong. The route URL is like /user/2/bids.

### EDIT - SOLVED

I found that the below works:

```
 $user_id = \DB::table($resourceName)->find($request->id)->user_id;
```

instead of

```
 $resourceId = $request->route()->parameter($resourceName);
 $user_id = \DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)->user_id;
```

This works with the routes like

> Route::get('/{id}/bids'

### EDIT - SOLVED - Other solution

```
$resourceId = $request->route()->parameter($resourceName);
$user_id = \DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)->user_id;
```

will work if the route is changed to

> Route::get('/{bids}/bids'

... instead of

> Route::get('/{id}/bids'...

Comment: Cab you *var_dump* `$resourceName` and see what you have?

Comment: dd($resourceName) returns "bids" and dd($resourceId) returns null (which is expected seen the error message, but I don't understand why it returns null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route like this `Route::get('user/{bids}/bids'...` becasse to get a route parameter like this `$request->route()->parameter('name')` it has to match the parameter name in the route, meaning the bolded one user/**{bids}**/bids.

Comment: Does this affect other parts of the code (e.g in controller etc?)

Comment: I have added a solution to my original question. Can you have a look and let me know if this is equally well?

Comment: @wiwa1978 yes, your code is ok. The problem is you're trying to get a named route parameter from the route that does not exist ( you're trying the get **bids** parameter when your parameter is named **id**). `$request->id` will work only if all of your rotes are declared with this parameter **{id}**.

Comment: I added both solutions to my original question. Both seem to work. Is there an advantage to using {bids} instead of {id} as I tend to use {id} all the time.

Comment: The advantage is that you know **bids** is a bid ID and if it's just **id** it could be user ID, bid ID, other model ID, etc. @wiwa1978

Answer (score 0):

`\DB::table($resourceName)->find($resourceId)` is returning null (no results), so there's no `user_id` property to it. Check that you've found a result before attempting to access its properties.

Same thing for $request->user()->id - if `$request->user()` is null due to the user not being logged in, it'll fail.

Comment: You mean adding a statement like   if ($resourceId == null) {
            abort(500, 'Internal error');
        } in my code?

Comment: @wiwa1978 Maybe, but you also need to account for a valid non-null $resourceId that doesn't exist in your database. You should also consider `dd()`ing your variables and query results to figure out what they contain - chances are they're not what you expect when you hit a bug.